# Powering two small power strips from one wall outlet?

Tags: power

I want to integrate 6 outlets into a furniture design I'm currently building, however I can't fit a power strip of that size.
An alternative could be to install two power strips with 3 outlets at two different locations.
The issue is that I only have a single wall outlet where the furniture piece is meant to go, so I would have to power both from the that same source.

Each power strip with 3 outlets is rated for a maximum of **3680W**.

I've calculated the total maximum power requirement of the appliances that would be connected to about **650W** with their individual maximum requirements. It's mainly a computer and periphery that would be connected here. The most extreme appliance that's not included would be a vacuum from time to time.

Could I simply connect both power strips in series and would that be safe for my scenario?

Comment: Well, for electrical safety, power strips should not be chained and used permanently or under long-term use anyway, which is exactly what you are proposing. We also don't know the copper wire rating (gauge, area) and if it should be trusted or not. We also don't know your local electrical codes what's allowed or not.

Comment: This seemed like a reasonable question until you mentioned the vacuum cleaner; they draw a high load and can cause surges that damage other equipment.  They should be plugged directly into the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something no sane person would answer *Yes* to. It can be done, it is being done all the time all around the globe, but if someone say *it's ok* and then these strips will be used - despite what you say - over their limit and something happens, the person that gave Ok will have a amount of responsibility.

Edit: It's better you hire an certified electrician to give advice and do wiring.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. After a little research I found a plug-and-play modular solution that should work.

Comment: I'm happy to hear, good luck with the furniture design!